# Convert XMRig miner and its configurations into single executable file (.exe) for Windows?

Tags: mining, windows, xmrig

I have setup a XMRig miner on my Windows 11 and it runs perfectly, I want to convert this XMRig miner file and its configuration( config.json) into a single executable and upload on GitHub. And later when I want to run this on another Windows computer, I'd have to simply run git clone. That way I would not have to go through setup steps again.

Please tell me the steps involved and how I could achieve this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can build XMRig with an *embedded* config. See this [issue comment](https://github.com/xmrig/xmrig/issues/957#issuecomment-468890667):

> 1. Use cmake option `-DWITH_EMBEDDED_CONFIG=ON` to enable this feature.
> 2. Edit/replace config sample in code
>    [src/core/config/Config_default.h#L31](https://github.com/xmrig/xmrig/blob/master/src/core/config/Config_default.h#L31)
> 3. Recompile the miner.